# Austria - Czech Republic - Germany - What is the best option for mobile phone

Tags: germany, internet, austria, czech-republic, mobile-operators

I'm planning to spend about 10 days in Austria, Czech Republic and Germany, starting in Austria.

I'd like to have mobile internet for maps and getting information about cities. I'd like also to have the possibility to call foreign and maybe local numbers sometimes. It will be good if the card is ready to use just after purchase.

I wonder if there are any cards offering something like no-roaming tariffs for neighbouring countries or offering a reasonable price for my purposes in all three countries.

Does something like that exists? If not, what would be the nearest hit?

Comment: If you wait for a year, there is currently a law being passed in the EU that will force provider to not charge additional costs for roaming in other EU members.

Answer (score 2):

All telecom operators in Europe provide [pretty much the same roaming rates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_roaming_regulations#Common_limits).

I would suggest getting three separate cards for all three countries:

[Austria](http://prepaidwithdata.wikia.com/wiki/Austria)

Czech Republic - get a prepaid Vodafone card

[Germany](http://prepaidwithdata.wikia.com/wiki/Germany)

Otherwise just buy a sim-card in Austria and be ready to pay the roaming rates from the first link.